# Why is toggleClass not working here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, frontend

I'm trying to add / remove a class on click here, but toggleClass is not working as I'm expecting it to. On the contrary, addClass works fine, but I need it to remove the class on the second click.

```
$('.label1').on('click', function() {
    var $checkItem = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
    $checkItem.prop("checked", !$checkItem.prop("checked"));
})

$('.label2').on('click', function() {
    var $checkItem = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');
    $(this).addClass('checked');
    $checkItem.prop("checked", !$checkItem.prop("checked"));
})
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

See it in action here: [Test jquery](https://codepen.io/rigilk/pen/OgozOo/).

Thanks!

Comment: Sharing the HTML would be more helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can avoid the problem and simplify your logic by instead hooking to the `change` event of the checkbox. This then lets you set the `checked` class on the parent `label` based on the state of the `checked` property.

Using `change` over `click` on the checkbox is also much better for meeting accessibility standards as it allows users who navigate using the keyboard to trigger the same effects in the UI. Try this:

```js
$(':checkbox').on('change', function() {
  $(this).closest('label').toggleClass('checked', this.checked)
});
```

```css
.checked {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="label1">
      <input type="checkbox">
      Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="label2">
      <input type="checkbox">
      Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Very elegant solution using closest.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can do it like this.

Try this example hope it will helps you.

```js
$('.label1').on('click', function() {
    var $checkItem = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');

    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
    if($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
       $checkItem.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
        $checkItem.prop("checked", false);
    }
  })

  $('.label2').on('click', function() {
    var $checkItem = $(this).find('input[type=checkbox]');

   
    if($(this).hasClass('checked')) {
       $checkItem.prop("checked", false);
        $(this).removeClass('checked');
    } else {
       $(this).addClass('checked');
        $checkItem.prop("checked", true);
    }
  })
```

```css
.checked {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="label1">
      <input type="checkbox">
      Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="label2">
      <input type="checkbox">
      Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

The checkbox is inside you label so when it gets clicked it is clicking the checkbox too.

```
  $('.label1, .label2').on('change', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
  })
```

https://codepen.io/ankurace/pen/OgoQLG

Answer (score 1):

This is a compact solution

```
$('input[type=checkbox].BorderRed').change(function() {
      $($(this).parent()).toggleClass('checked');
});
```

NEW checkbox Object,

> if you wont the effect

```
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="label2">
      <input class="BorderRed" type="checkbox">
      Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
```

> if you dont wont the effect

```
  <div class="checkbox">
    <label class="label2">
      <input type="checkbox">
      Check me out
    </label>
  </div>
```